# Filter items with css only

Tags: html, css, select, filter, tabindex

I want to filter a list of items with css only. The list should filter the items when a specific link is clicked.

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Header links -->
<a href="#" class="all" tabindex="-1" title="All" >All</a> 
<a href="#" class="web" tabindex="-1" title="Web">Web</a> 
<a href="#" class="graphic" tabindex="-1" title="Graphic">Graphic</a> 
<a href="#" class="music" tabindex="-1" title="Music">Music</a>

<!-- Content -->
<li class="web"><a href="#">Web</a></li>
<li class="music"><a href="#">Music</a></li>
<li class="graphic"><a href="#">Graphic</a></li>
<li class="web"><a href="#">Web</a></li>
<li class="music"><a href="#">Music</a></li>
<li class="graphic"><a href="#">Graphic</a></li
<li class="music"><a href="#">Music</a></li>
<li class="graphic"><a href="#">Graphic</a></li>
```

**CSS**

```
a[class="web"]:focus ~ li:not([class="web"]) {
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    border:none;
    margin:0;
    display:none;
}
a[class="graphic"]:focus ~ li:not([class="graphic"]) {
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    border:none;
    margin:0;
    display:none;
}
a[class="music"]:focus ~ li:not([class="music"]) {
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    border:none;
    margin:0;
    display:none;
}
```

I want to place a `div` around the header links. But this wrapping `div` breaks the functionality. How can I achieve that?

Here is a [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j8a859k3/)

Comment: Why do you have `tabindex: "-1"`?

Comment: You should include your CSS in the question; the (clever!) way you are achieving the filtering functionality - via a `:focus` pseudo-selector and a sibling selector - is currently non-obvious without following the JSFiddle link. I do not think it is possible today for you to achieve the functionality you want if you wrap the `<a>`s in a `<div>`, because I do not think there is any way to write CSS that targets a `<li>` that has a focused `<a>` as a *nephew*. If browsers ever implement a [parent selector](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/1709587), things would be different.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have a `div` around the `a` tags, but you will also need to have  the `li` items in the same container. The reason for that is because there aren't parent selectors yet available in CSS.

Why do you want to have a div around the `a` headers?

If that is because of styling them, why not specifying the `a` classes you want for the heading links and then add CSS:

```
a.all, a.web, a.graphic, a.music {
  // Your heading css
}
```

Here is an example: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbPYNX

Comment: Is it possible to add a block div around a tags?